# Checking dates if between range of dates in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `booked` table with `start` and `end` column as datestamps;

I know that this

```
$start = "2015-07-12 01:00:00";
$end = "2015-07-12 02:00:00";

$users = DB::table('booked')
                    ->whereBetween('start', [$start, $end])->get();
```

checks for any dates in `start` column that falls within $start and $end.

What I want is actually the other way.

Am having difficulty checking for $start and $end date variables occurrences in `start` and `end` columns in `book` table.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other way"? Records that have start date outside given start/end range?

Comment: the way I understand it is that the query above checks whether start column is between $start and $end or not.  what I want to find out is whether $start and $end falls between column `start` and `end`.

Answer (score 7):

```
// make sure $from is before $till, because they are probably provided as input
$from = min($start, $end);
$till = max($start, $end);

// then simply
DB::table('booked')
     ->where('start', '<=', $from)
     ->where('end', '>=', $till)
     ->get();
```

It will return rows matching `$from-$till` period contained in `start-end` period:

```
    start                     end
      |------------------------|
         |----------------|
       $from            $till
```

Comment: very simple and brilliant solution

Comment: Instead of ordering `$start` and `$end` dates, wouldn't be nicer to actually validate them in the first place to ensure that `$start` contains a date that is before `$end`? With Laravel's current validation rules you could do that in a simple way. Otherwise in a hypothetical form you might see: "look for a booking from 28 Jan 2020 to 20 Jan 2020" and that would result in a correct query, but it should be a validation error to me

Comment: Hi Jarek, I like this solution. I just have a related question. Is it possible to get only that rows, which is not between the start and end? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Please Try under given code this will check is requested dates time are already book or not, if any time slot is booked then it will return 1 otherwise 0 :

```
$start = $request->start_date; 
$end = $request->end_date; 
DB::table('booked')->where(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {

    $query->where(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('start', '>=', $start)
           ->where('start', '<', $end);

    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('start', '<=', $start)
           ->where('end', '>', $end);

    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('end', '>', $start)
           ->where('end', '<=', $end);

    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('start', '>=', $start)
           ->where('end', '<=', $end);
    });

})->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with this code, in my case, I have multiple blocked dates, in which we can't allow user to register a new booking, so we have to check the following 12 Wheres:

```
$start_date = $request->start_date; 
$end_date = $request->end_date; 
DB::table('booked')->where(function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
    $query->where(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $q->where('start_date', '>=', $start_date)
            ->where('start_date', '=<', $start_date);
    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $q->where('end_date', '>=', $start_date)
            ->where('end_date', '<=', $start_date);
    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $q->where('start_date', '>=', $end_date)
            ->where('start_date', '<=', $end_date);
    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $q->where('end_date', '>=', $end_date)
            ->where('end_date', '<=', $end_date);
    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $q->where('start_date', '<=', $start_date)
            ->where('end_date', '>=', $start_date);
    })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $q->where('start_date', '<=', $end_date)
            ->where('end_date', '>=', $end_date);
    });
})->count();
```

Answer (score -1):

The following query will give you all records for which **both start and end are between $start and $end**:

```
$users = DB::table('booked')
  ->where('start', '>=', $start)
  ->where('start', '<=', $end)
  ->where('end', '>=', $start)
  ->where('end', '<=', $end);
```